# How to stop a running thread under following condition in ANDROID

Tags: java, android, multithreading, media-player

in my app when user clicks on a spell button then it play audio to read outs letters of a word with displaying each letters. It is implemented successfully!.

And  i used swipe gesture to change the word. if user swipes the screen then  another word should be displayed. and  It also implemented successfully!!

**Problem:**
While audio is playing if user swipes then the audio should stop and next word shold be displayed.(I guess the **running thread should be stopped**).

**How can i do that? Any Solution?**

**Code Outlines:**

```
public class BirdsActivity extends Activity implements OnClickListener{

//On createMethod*(){
.
.
  //on Spell button click run a thread to play audio and draw text
    new DrawLetter("AlphaKids").start();

// initiate Gesture detection

  }


class DrawLetter extends Thread {
    String tempName=names[position];    
    String b="";
    int i=0;
    public DrawLetter(String str) {
    super(str);
    }
    public void run() {

        for (int i = 0; i < names[position].length(); i++) {
     runOnUiThread(new Runnable()
                {               
                     public void run() 
                  {     txtFrontName.setText(b); }

                });

            mPlayVoice = MediaPlayer.create(BirdsActivity.this, mAlphabetsSound[letterPosition]);
                mPlayVoice.start();
                try {
            sleep(500); 
            mPlayVoice.release();
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {}
     }}
.
.
.
  // Gesture detection class

@Override
    public boolean onFling(MotionEvent e1, MotionEvent e2, float velocityX, float velocityY) {

      //if  valid swipe is performed
      {  
            //i want to stop(or Distroy) the above thread here

     }
} }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess you don't have to destroy the thread your self. Stop the music mPlayVoice.stop(); since the variable is declared in UIThread ... it can be accessed in UIThread and you can stop your player from there. most probably in handler.

Comment: sorry.. mPlayVoice.stop() stops mediya player but while thread is running it again starts

Comment: I dont quite understand your code. Why is Mediaplayer start inside a loop in your thread? Are you playing multiple files? Consider updating your question to make it more clear.

Comment: ok.... initialize your mPlayVoice inside UI thread rather than initializing into run method of new thread. Like  mPlayVoice = MediaPlayer.create(BirdsActivity.this, mAlphabetsSound[letterPosition]);  do this in UIThread. I mean in your code above your runOnUIThread Line. .. I guess it should now solve your problem

Comment: @success_anil Anyway Sorry.. i can stop the media player but thread is still runs no? it wont be a problem?

Comment: hmm. your can use handlers in android to switch between UIThread and other Thread. send me your question at success_anil@yahoo.co.in.. I will send a  code to implement handler ... you can modify the code to your requirements

Answer (score 0):

```
 mPlayVoice.stop()
```

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/MediaPlayer.html

/edit

```
boolean shouldPlayVoice = true;
...
if(shouldPlayVoice){
mPlayVoice.start();
}
...
mPlayVoice.stop();
shouldPlayVoice = false;
```

Comment: sorry.. mPlayVoice.stop() stops mediya player but while thread is running it again starts